Landsat 9 level 2 pansharpening
I would like to increase the spatial resolution of the Landsat 9 data (bands 1 to 7) from my study region by creating pansharpened raster data sets in ArcGIS. However, the band 8 (panchromatic band) is not part of the level 2 Landsat data. Is it possible to use the panchromatic band of the level 1 Landsat 9 data to pansharpen level 2 data or can this cause any errors within the data?
